# How can I find out the crypto exchange name from the below ERC20 crypto address?

Tags: erc-20, exchanges, cryptography

How can I find out the **crypto exchange name from the below ERC20 crypto addresses**?

I) 0xc261b02dafbe844b6b30d96bcaba14f2a04e3cc8

II) 0x699076cBd255C4e1F779C7e3CA**strong text**E88e09846aDF83

Comment: What do you mean by "crypto exchange name"?

Comment: Crypto Exchange name I mean the name of exchange where this crypto addresses is hosted on or belongs to. This crypto address is generated by some crypto exchange.I want to find out the name of that exhange.